# Square of a mod

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find $9^{16} \pmod{25}$ by separation.

The separation means, that $25 = 5^2$.

But $9^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, so I how I derive that $9^{16} \equiv 16 \pmod{25}$?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Don't go for such hasty processes.
$$9^{3}\equiv 4 \,\ (\mod 25)$$
$$9^{15}\equiv 4^5\equiv 1024\equiv -1 \,\ (\mod 25)$$
$$9^{16}\equiv -9 \,\ (\mod 25)$$
$$9^{16}\equiv 16 \,\ (\mod 25)$$
Your problem is solved.

As such there is no such way to separate the expression in modulo. Check the formulas please.

Answer (score 0):

As $9=3^2,9^{16}=(3^2)^{16}=3^{32}$

Now $3^3\equiv2\pmod{25}\implies3^{32}=3^2(3^3)^{10}\equiv3^2\cdot2^{10}$

Now $2^5\equiv7\implies2^{10}=(2^5)^2\equiv7^2\equiv-1$

$\implies3^2\cdot2^{10}\equiv9\cdot-1\equiv16$